# How to improve the looks of a fraction?

Tags: equations, fractions

We may notice that the numerator and denominator in the following fraction are not aligned. And, to me it does not look good.

How to align the numerator and denominator?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,xcolor,mathtools}

\let\xoverline\overline % supply your definition

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The above yields:

[image]

Comment: Not a real improvement, but here it is: `\frac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k^{\hphantom{m+n+d}}}`

Comment: @student What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: In my opinion, aligning them is not a good idea, since the terms are importantly different. As well, as @egreg points out, the "aligned" result is not much good nicer. You can maybe shift the denominator just slightly: `\dfrac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k\quad}` But I'm not sure it looks nicer than the default one.

Comment: @tohecz I'd definitely use the default centering.

Comment: Possible duplicate (and solutions): [\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} doesn't look very good and how to leave space equal to the size of a given text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4229)

Comment: @egreg: maybe more compact: `\dfrac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k\hfill}`

Comment: @morbusg Yes, in this particular case.

Comment: An what about `\dfrac{1-k^S}{1-k}` with `S=m+n+d` ?

Comment: You can insert thick spaces `\; `: 
     `\[
    \dfrac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{\;\;1-k}
     \]` or `\[
\frac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k\;\;}
\]`

Comment: Here is yet another suggestion: `\frac{1-k^{\mathrlap{m+n+d}}}{1-k}`. I'd still recommend leaving it as is or using `\hphantom` as per @egreg's solution.  This requires the `mathtools` package to use as is. Otherwise use `\rlap{$ ... $}`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a comparison of the proposed solutions; the name next to the fraction doesn't necessarily denote the suggestion author's preference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\makebox[2in][l]{1. Original}$\dfrac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k}$

\bigskip

\makebox[2in][l]{2. egreg}$\dfrac{1-k^{m+n+d}}{1-k^{\hphantom{m+n+d}}}$

\bigskip

\makebox[2in][l]{3. projetmbc}$\dfrac{1-k^S}{1-k}, \text{ with $S=m+n+d$}$

\bigskip

\makebox[2in][l]{4. Peter Grill}$\dfrac{1-k^{\mathrlap{m+n+d}}}{1-k}$


\end{document}
```

Take your pick.

[image]

Everybody can add here their personal preference.

- egreg: version 1 (with an eye to 3)