# Aligned numerator and denominator in \frac or any other variant

Tags: math-mode, fractions

Is there a way to align the numerator and the denominator of a fraction? Consider two fractions (from a SIAM paper)
[image]

The denominator (k!) is nicely centred in the first fraction. However in the second fraction the brackets in the numerator and the denominator are not aligned. As the exponent of the numerator gets bigger, the misalignment gets worse. In general, the strategy of centring numerator and denominator is correct. However, it would be good to have the option of aligning brackets in specific instances like this.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
   $\dfrac{(x_i - x)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The numerator and denominator are horizontally centered with respect to one another; this is by far the most common typographic treatment of fractions.

Comment: @egreg So am I better off with the default latex behaviour?

Comment: In the first fraction it seems that `k!` is aligned to the minus sign, but try writing `(z-x)^{k}` as numerator and you'll see the effect of centering. In my opinion there is no sensible way to align differently the two parts.

Comment: @egreg Yeah. I played around with various denominators. More and more I feel like this question is a bad idea. I am going to delete it.

Comment: With the `mathtools` package providing the `\mathrlap` macro you _could_ do (in the denominator) `(N+1)\mathrlap{!}\hphantom{^{N+1}}` or, in this simple case, `(N+1)^{N+1}\hfill`. For the latter already exist a then-abused macro: `\cfrac[l]{(x_i - x)^{N+1}}{(N+1)^{N+1}}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\cfrac` is meant for typesetting continued fractions.

Comment: @egreg “abused”

Comment: @devendra Although I would recommend to use just the default LaTeX style in your case, here are some related questions: [How to improve the looks of a fraction?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73998/16595), [`\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}` doesn't look very good …](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4229/16595)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you. Should I leave this question or just delete it. People might come here and then see your comments.

Comment: Related Question: [Align denominator of fraction to left](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84243/align-denominator-of-fraction-to-left/).

Comment: @devendra: I would recommend not deleting the question (but perhaps others disagree). Am sure others will come up with a similar question in the future (see Related Question I linked to) and if the answer is that is a bad idea to do this that may save them the time to post another question. Knowing what _not_ to do is usually a good thing to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As illustrated in the highest-voted answer to [Align denominator of fraction to left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84243/align-denominator-of-fraction-to-left/), `\hfill` will do the trick.

Here's a macro, `\myfrac`, that puts the `\hfill` either in the numerator or the denominator as necessary

```
\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{$#1$}        % put the numerator in box0
    \dimen0=\wd0               % measure box0
    \setbox1\hbox{$#2$}        % put the denominator in box1
    \dimen1=\wd1               % measure box1
    \ifdim\wd0<\wd1            % if box0 is narrower than box1
        \dfrac{#1\hfill}{#2}   % put \hfill in the numerator
    \else                      
        \dfrac{#1}{#2\hfill}   % otherwise put \hfill in the denominator
    \fi
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{$#1$}        % put the numerator in box0
    \dimen0=\wd0               % measure box0
    \setbox1\hbox{$#2$}        % put the denominator in box1
    \dimen1=\wd1               % measure box1
    \ifdim\wd0<\wd1            % if box0 is narrower than box1
        \dfrac{#1\hfill}{#2}   % put \hfill in the numerator
    \else                      
        \dfrac{#1}{#2\hfill}   % otherwise put \hfill in the denominator
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[Original] $\dfrac{(x_i - x)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$
    \item[Test 1] $\myfrac{(x_i - x)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$
    \item[Test 2] $\myfrac{(N+1)!}{(x_i - x)^{N+1}}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{\dfrac{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}` produce the same (horrible) output?

Comment: @egreg ah, yes, of course :) My code is unnecessarily complicated- thanks for catching :)