# How can I improve alignment of the numerator and denominator when vector norm bars along with subscripts throw things off?

Tags: math-mode, fractions, physics

Here's the really bad case:

[image]

With a red bar to show what is bothering me in particular:

[image]

Here's a simpler case where the issue is a non-issue, but perhaps one can get a hint of why it starts to get bad:

[image]
[image]

Here's some minimum code to produce the problem examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\ensuremath{{#1}_{p}}}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normv}[2][p]{%
    \ensuremath{\norm{\vec{#2}}_{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        0 = \frac{x}{\mycommand{x}}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \vec{x} = \frac{\vec{x}}{\normv{x}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I got the following bit of code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88237/aligned-numerator-and-denominator-in-frac-or-any-other-variant):

```
\newcommand{\alignedvfrac}[2]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{$#1$}        % put the numerator in box0
    \dimen0=\wd0               % measure box0
    \setbox1\hbox{$#2$}        % put the denominator in box1
    \dimen1=\wd1               % measure box1
    \ifdim\wd0<\wd1            % if box0 is narrower than box1
    \dfrac{#1\hfill}{#2}   % put \hfill in the numerator
    \else                      
    \dfrac{#1}{#2\hfill}   % otherwise put \hfill in the denominator
    \fi
}
```

Using it does not help:

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't work as it seems that the problems are basically the same. Can you help me understand?

Comment: you could make it symmetric using \hphantom{{}_p} on the left side

Comment: for the first case (with the double verts), you can use `\mathrlap{_p)` to make the subscript have "no width".  requires `mathtools`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That works beautifully. So if I understand correctly, `\mathrlap{_p}` basically "hides" the subscript in the calculation for the box size?

Comment: @barbarabeeton the reason why I ask is because if put double verts around the whole fraction, the double verts overlap on the `_p`, and there are other such clashes..., so somehow, I need it to go into `mathrlap` *only* for the alignment of the numerator and denominator, but then revert back to normal mode

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned with that nonalignment. There's no reason for the two letters being aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution, which consists in adding a phantom prescript to the norm. As the fraction line might a little wide, acorrection might be necessary (more typing… but part of the correction can be incorporated to the norm command. Also, as I don't have the physics package installed, I defined the `norm` command with the help of `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{physics}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\ensuremath{{#1}_{p}}}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\normv}[2][p]{%
    \ensuremath{{}_{\phantom{#1}}\norm{\vec{#2}}_{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\normw}[2][p]{%
    \ensuremath{{}_{\!\phantom{#1}}\norm{\vec{#2}}_{#1}\!}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        0 = \frac{x}{\mycommand{x}}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \vec{x} = \frac{\vec{x}}{\normv{x}}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \vec{x} = \frac{\!\vec{x}\!}{\normw{x}}
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer! What are the `\!` commands called?

Comment: It adds a negative thin space (works only in math mode), just as `\,` adds a thin space..